# How to print $terms in Omega theme?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, theming

I´m using an Omega subtheme in D7 and I can´t print all terms inside a specific vocabulary belonging to a node.

I´ve tried:

`<?php print render($terms); ?>` It prints nothing.

`<?php print $terms; ?>` It prints this error only: **Notice: Undefined variable: terms**

And this: `<?php print render($content['taxonomy_vocabulary_5']); ?>` wich prints nothing.

Comment: This does not depend on the theme you're using. What do you try to do? Is this in a template file or in a preprocessor or somewhere else?

Comment: if this is in a template file and you have the devel module enabled, you can see all the variables you have access to with     dpm(get_defined_vars());

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it is in a template file!